# FFMPEG video overlay video loop error, file too big, endless process

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using a FFMPEG cmd to display 1 video (about 10-50 seconds) overlay on top of a background video (about 5 seconds), and it will scale the input video and add a fade in effect.

Most of the time, it will work without errors, but sometimes it will have errors: the process does not end, the file is very large, 10-30 GB and I have to kill the process manually.

Please help me to see if this command is the problem, the input videos are all the same format and there is no difference.

If I can't fix it, I'll have to use a static background image and remove the stream_loop parameter.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i bg.mp4 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=720:-1,fade=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1[i];[0][i]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1" output.mp4
```